# How to mark a cell value as mandatory

Tags: excel

How to mark a cell value as mandatory in excel. I have a sheet which contains 3 headers and I would like to mark the column values of header3 as mandatory from a possible set of values (i.e. even if the user doesn't select a value a default value should be set for the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Validation on Cells where you want to perform these constraints.

Like : Select Range of Cells where you want to put this constraint.

Now open `Data Validation` Dialog and Select `List` from `Allow` drop down in `Setting Tab`. Provide your `source` (possible values) in comma separate values

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do with the help of c# code Try this : -

```
Worksheet ws;
Range oRng = ws.get_Range(StartCol + StartRow, EndCol + EndRow);
oRng.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateDecimal, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, "StartVal", "EndVal");
                                oRng.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
                                oRng.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
                                oRng.Validation.ErrorTitle = "Input Error";
                                oRng.Validation.ErrorMessage = "Please enter a numeric
```

value between "StartVal" and "EndVal"";
                                oRng.Validation.ShowError = true;

where ws is the worksheet object, StartVal and EndVal are the range of values for which validation is to be checked